# How to loop canvas objects(images/cars)?

Tags: java, jframe, 2d

I am trying to make some movable cars in JFrame(Canvas) to make a game. 
I am using this type of code to move the position of the image object.

```
 public void tick() {
        z += 1;
    }
```

but it always run once. And it go through JFrame. 
How do i make the object to loop infinity like cars?

Comment: You run it in an infinite loop until some escape condition is satisfied. If this is your first time coding in java, then you should learn the basics first and about loops, rather than trying to make a game.

Comment: i am not new to programming. but i am new to game programming. Currently i am trying to understand how this things works.

Comment: You run everything in an infinite loop which you break when conditions are met. So for example. `boolean run = true; while(run) { .. do stuff }`.  if they press q on the keyboard, set run to false, it they press up arrow then trigger `tick`. That's the basics. This is really the wrong place to be asking since you don't have a coding question. A simple google search and you can find guides on how to make java games.